# Magento 1.9 throws 500 error when user try to register

Tags: php, apache, http, magento, magento-1.9

I have Magento version 1.9.3.2. When a user wants to register, it generates an *Internal Server Error* (HTTP error code 500). The user does **not** receive email, but he **is registered**.

If I reload the page, it shows the message *"Thank you for registering"* and account page is open.

I checked logs of Magento and Apache - nothing there.

Anybody have idea how to fix this?

Update. 
I switched on display_errors in index.php file. I got message:

[05-Jul-2017 09:09:01 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getPayment() on null in /home/some/public_html/some/app/code/community/Fooman/EmailAttachments/Model/Core/Email/Template/Mailer.php on line 34

This line 34 is this:
$paymentMethod = $this->getTemplateParams()['order']->getPayment()->getData("method");

So seems there is a block "Fooman" which tries to use instance of the class when it is not initialised.

Anybody know something about this extension Fooman?

Update.
Seems the problem is solved by this code. For registration I check if user has instance of class, if he don't have it I use standard template.

```
//here check if have instance of class
            if (isset($this->getTemplateParams()['order']))
            {
                //here 34 string where error occure
                $paymentMethod = $this->getTemplateParams()['order']->getPayment()->getData("method");

                if ($this->getTemplateId() == '1') {
                    switch($paymentMethod) {
                        case 'banktransfer':
                            $templateId = 9;
                            break;

                        case 'paypal_express':
                            $templateId = 8;

                        default:
                            $templateId = $this->getTemplateId();
                            break;
                    }
                } else {

                    $templateId = $this->getTemplateId();
                }
            }
            else {
                $templateId = $this->getTemplateId();
            }
```

Comment: un-comment display errors on from index.php and test again may be you will see the error

Answer (score 0):

some time when file not found Emogrifier.php below path

magento Root/lib/Pelago/Emogrifier.php

Check this file exist or not if it is not there then download from fresh magento and put it to there.

clear cache and try.

Comment: File exists, it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

If you get the internal server error 500 then you must have to enable display error.

Go to `index.php`  and replace code

```
if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
}
with Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);

and use ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Use both one by one.